# Unable to get AWS SSL Certificate

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, django-rest-framework, ssl-certificate

I am trying to make my Django REST API get HTTPS,
For that using AWS Certificate manager,I tried to create a certificate using public DNS IPV4 `ec2-52-66-238-9.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
It shows validation failed with both Email validation and DNS validation and i don't wanna buy a domain to get it.Is there any way?

Comment: You can't add ssl to that domain. But you can add  https support easily by using CloudFront in-front of your instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the SSL certificate for a domain that you own and have control over.

Comment: So, I Cant get SSL for the domain given by AWS as public DNS?

Comment: Not through ACM I am afraid

Comment: Actually, you can't do that due to `compute.amazonaws.com` is not your domain, you don't have the right to issue an SSL certificate with a domain not yours.